# using multiple cases in receive call in Scala Actor model

Tags: scala, actor

I am new to this fancy language called Scala.

I have enough (I guess) programming experience in C++.
As a programming exercise I was trying to use Scala's Actor model to add the elements of an array. I create a class named workerActor.
In my main method I create an object of this class and then try to send messages to this object (which is an actor as I extend my class from Actor class in Scala).
When I pass a string to the actor, the code inside the act method gets executed and logic goes to the correct case and everyone is happy.
However, when I try to pass a tuple to the object like
sample ! (2,4,arr)

2 and 4 are the indexes in the array which I want my actor to do computation on and arr is the array I want to pass, it shows me error.
How do I pass the array and the indexes to my array to the Actor.
Does Scala allow to pass tuples to actors?

As an interesting observation I realized that if I have a second case in my act() method i get a compilation error.
Eclipse shows me unreachable code.
Any idea what can be the issue why I can't use a second case in the receive method.

```
case object add
case object trial

import scala.actors._
import Actor._

class workerActor(arr: Array[Int]) extends Actor{
def addarr(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
var sum = 0
for (i <- a to b)
  sum += arr(i)
  println("Sum :",a,b,sum)
sum
}
def act(){
   receive {
   case trial => println("Received trial")
   //case trial => println("Received add") //uncommenting this line does not compile the program
   }
}
}

object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
    val arr = Array(1,2,3,4,5,7,13,4,6,6,23);
    val sample = new workerActor(arr)
    val s = sample.addarr(2, 4,arr)
    sample ! (2,4)
    sample ! "try"
    sample ! add
    sample.start   
    sample ! trial
  }
}
```

Rather than an issue with passing tuple this looks to be a weird issue (maybe syntax) of having multiple cases in receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in a case statement, Scala treats identifiers that start with lowercase letters as variables, so it is actually assigning a new variable called "trial" in the first case:

```
case trial => println("Received trial")
case add   => println("Received add")
```

We can see the "assignment" behavior in a simple example:

```
scala> 5 match { case something => println("matched " + something) }
matched 5
```

When `trial` is just an assignable variable, it can match anything, so the first case will always succeed... for both `trial` and `add` objects.  Since the first case always succeeds, you get an error telling you that the second case is unreachable.

To fix this, you need to use a "stable identifier".  Stable identifiers are contained in backticks:

```
case `trial` => println("Received trial")
case `add`   => println("Received add")
```

or start with an uppercase letter:

```
case object Add
case object Trial

...

case Trial => println("Received trial")
case Add   => println("Received add")
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response..
Worked perfect.. Any pointers on good tutorials for Scala as am very new to it?

Comment: @Deepti, Happy to help.  I learned Scala by reading answers on StackOverflow, so I'd consider that a pretty good tutorial :-)

Comment: I recommend reading "Scala for the Impatient" or "Programming in Scala" to start things off, followed by "Scala in Depth." And of course, reading StackOverflow Scala questions. :-) Also, word of advice, for actors, use Akka Actors, which will be the default implementation in Scala 2.10 when it comes out. For <= 2.9.x, you can download it at www.akka.io or just list it as an SBT dependency.